# Write code to match a specific Big-O-Notation

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

Our class was challenged by a professor at uni that if we were able to find a algorithm that fittingly describes the following Big-O-Notation, we'd instantly pass his class. I wanted to ask if any of you know how this could be done since I've been struggling to make it work without just simplifying it. (Could be any language, i chose c++ for my example)

##### O(4n · (-2 + 3n) · (n - log(n)) / n) = ?

Simplifying it often gave me either O(n^2) or O(n^3) which would be easy enough to implement but i feel like is not the goal of the challenge.
I've tried directly changing each part into algorithm logic like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

void Algorithm(int n) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4 * n; ++i) { // outer loop iterates 4n times
        for (int j = 1; j <= -2 + 3 * n; ++j) { // middle loop  iterates (−2+3n) times
            for (int k = 1; k <= n - log(n); ++k) { // inner loop iterates (n−log(n)) times
                // Operations are performed here
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = 10; // Example value for n
    Algorithm(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Though I'm unsure whether that is correct

Comment: O(log N) usually works differently then putting in a hard coded call to `log`. For inspiration lookup binary search. That is an algorithm that works log(n)

Comment: This task is pointless. This inverts problem. You should have an algorithm then find its asymptotic time/memory complexity to reason algorithm efficiency. Doing this vice versa find algorithm which has this time complexity for me is useless task. Are you sure you understood your assignment correctly?

Comment: Whilst your code literally translates the O( ) expression he gave into a concrete example it isn't the simplest canonical form with that O( ) notation. The whole point of big O notation is to simplify down the core of most expensive operations and how they scale with size n. Random additive or multiplicative constants are just noise that obfuscates meaning. It boils down to O(n*(n-log n)) when the chaff is removed.

Comment: @AhmedAEK these are asymptotes (aka limits for large `n`), not actual arythmetic expressions, `O(n/2)` is same as `O(n)`. The time complexity of `O(n/2 - log(n)) ` simplifies to `O(n)` because the dominant term is n. The `log(n)` term is negligible compared to `n`, so it can be dropped. Therefore, the time complexity is `O(n)`.

Comment: Without simplification, I don't see which operations could have complexity `O(1/N)`...

Comment: It's equal to `O(n^2)` by definition.

Comment: *"a algorithm that fittingly describes the following Big-O-Notation"* -- What is this supposed to mean? It looks backwards. Big-O notation describes algorithms, not the other way around. Was this supposed to be an algorithm that **demonstrates** the (behavior described by the) big-O notation? Or maybe more simply an algorithm that fits the big-O notation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way:

```
def f(n)
  1.upto(4n · (-2 + 3n) · (n - log(n)) / n) do |i|
    // any O(1) operation here
  end
end
```

Though if your professor really meant O() instead of Theta() then any smaller expression would do.

Comment: @JaMiT Oops. Right. Fixed.